ICEBERG_BAD_DATA with Firehose Iceberg table destination
We have been trying Firehose for Iceberg Tables. The source is Kinesis stream attached to DynamoDB tables with some Lambda processing in between.
Table has been successfully filled by Firehose, but when we tried to run MERGE INTO using the source table as target target table, then the DML failed with ICEBERG_BAD_DATA: Multiple entries with same key: 2147483645=_pos and 2147483645=$row_id.pos.
I tried to isolate the problem, so I copied existing table into new one using CTAS and executed the same DML on it, which worked without any problem.
It seems like either we are not using Firehose properly or it damages the Iceberg table somehow.
Is this a documented thing or have we been using it in improper way?
The DML for merge is
MERGE INTO db.tab AS t
USING db.tab AS s
ON s.pk = t.pk AND s.sk = t.sk
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET _record_changed_at = s._record_changed_at || '_test';

The DDL for CTAS is
CREATE TABLE db.tab WITH (
    table_type = 'ICEBERG',
    format = 'PARQUET',
    location = 's3://bucket-export-${aws_account_id}-${aws_region_name}/data/test/test2',
    is_external = false,
    partitioning = ARRAY['account_id'],
    vacuum_max_snapshot_age_seconds = 604800,
    vacuum_min_snapshots_to_keep = 5
                                                    )
AS SELECT
       pk, sk, account_id
-- more columns go here
       FROM db.orig_tab;

The original table was crated with this DDL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS awsdatacatalog.db.orig_tab(
    pk string COMMENT 'Partition Key: PK',
    sk string COMMENT 'Sort Key: SK',
    account_id string COMMENT 'Customer account ID, <% map path=AccountId %>'
   -- more columns
)
COMMENT 'Mirror of DynamoDB Table'
PARTITIONED BY (account_id)
LOCATION 's3://data-export-${aws_account_id}-${aws_region_name}/data/glue/iceberg/db/orig_tab'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'table_type' = 'ICEBERG',
    'format' = 'parquet'
)
;

